# (Play framework 2.4) reverse routing images in client side?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.4

How would you do something like

```scala
@routes.Assets.versioned("images/....")
```

in client side?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: I guess with client side you mean in JavaScript in your browser? It's not possible. This is a service provided by Play only on the server side. But what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Kris it is possible, check my answer - and linked doc

Comment: @biesior Interesting! You write an action that returns the route. Simple solution. But I still can't imagine why one would want reverse routing on the client side?

Comment: @Kris, Maybe it doesn't make deeper sense while you're just going to fetch public, static assets, but It's quite useful when you have i.e. advanced JS application in the frontend, which accesses some complicated API , in this case it brings the same benefits as using reverse routing in common templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Javascript router](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaJavascriptRouting) for this as mentioned in the docs.

It can be declared within [dedicated action](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaJavascriptRouting#Router-resource), but you can also insert it directly into your template as [Embedded router](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaJavascriptRouting#Embedded-router) it's as easy as:

```
<head>
    ...

    @helper.javascriptRouter("jsRoutes")(
        routes.javascript.Assets.versioned
    )

    <script>
        console.log(jsRoutes.controllers.Assets.versioned("images/favicon.png" ).url);
    </script>

</head>
```